# How to remove recursion in EditText TextChangedListener?

Tags: android

I want to expurgate some bad words from edit text suppose. Father Uncle Cousin King will be F**K... But the problem is if I change the text it come to change handler again. Anyone know the solution. Please help. Code is there.

```
search_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            search_name.setText(s.toString().replace("something", "s**ething"));
            // here comes it repeatedly
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });
```

Comment: use a InputFilter instead.

Comment: I know about `InputFilter` but I need to remove this recursion for many cases.

Comment: if you are going to call setText in a TextWatcher, this is causing a recursion. You can use a flag to avoid calling setText in a recursion loop, or you can use InputFilters, which are more suitable for this use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with a variable. Got idea from @njzk2

```
int checker = 0;
search_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            checker = 0;
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
            if(checker!=1)
            {    
               checker = 1;
               search_name.setText(s.toString().replace("something", "s**ething"));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The TextWatcher documentation clearly says you should not be changing the text in onTextChanged.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @njzk2 comments re:InputFilter, if the recursion is the trouble you want to solve, you can try something like this to prevent it:

```
// make your TextWatcher a class variable
protected TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            textFixerUpper(search_name, s.toString());
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    };


protected textFixerUpper(EditText t, String s)
{
 t.removeTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);             // remove the listener
 t.setText(s.replace("something", "s**ething"));        // update the text
 t.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);                // add the listener back
}
```

or by setting a Boolean flag instead of removing and re-adding the listener....though either seems a bit messy.

Comment: This may OK to remove listener and add it again after work. But i do now think this the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate text via `Editable` instance provided by `afterTextChanged(e: Editable)` method:

```
val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(e: Editable) {
        e.insert(0, "Hello World")
        // e.delete(st, en) ...
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) { }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) { }
}
```

Listener methods are not called in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is control the `count` and `before` value

```
view.addTextChangedListener(
    ...

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
        if ( count - before != 0) {
            onTextChange(charSequence);
        }
    }

);
```